# Online code beautifier and formatter

Tags: code-formatting

What are the best online code beautifier and formatter out there? I'm not asking for highlighters. Any language will do.

Comment: viewed over 57k times... good thing you guys got on top of it and closed this

Comment: Over 61k times now, so about 4k views in the last month. Yes, definitely not a constructive question.

Comment: Not sure why this topic was closed, but http://tohtml.com/javaProperties/ worked well for me.  The styles and color are "inline" which makes it very simple to copy and paste into something else.

Answer (score 108):

CSS: [code beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)

HTML: [HTML Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/), [CleanUp HTML](http://www.cleanuphtml.com/cleanup.html) or the general purpose [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&html)

Javascript: http://jsbeautifier.org/

PHP: http://beta.phpformatter.com/

SQL: http://dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

XML: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Colour all: http://quickhighlighter.com/

Comment: Can you suggest any formatter which follow PSR-2 code standard for PHP?

Comment: For SQL formatting there is the free online Formatter SQLinForm http://www.sqlinform.com/sql_formatter_online.html

Comment: I dont find anything for AWK. Surprised

Comment: or use pastebin and highlight code for a variety of languages - http://pastebin.com/

Comment: For VB indentation: http://warp.senecac.on.ca/timothy.mckenna/CodeFormatter.asp

Comment: has anyone a Code Beautifier (not a highlighter) for PHP7?

Answer (score 25):

For PHP, Java, C++, C, Perl, JavaScript, CSS you can try:

http://www.prettyprinter.de/index.php

Comment: Did you actually try this one? It outputs `&gt;` for `>` and similar.

Comment: I think that is because those will be embedded inside another html page, as a sample, etc, and really should be.

Comment: It outputs < for `&lt;`...

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Perl::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy) for Perl.

Answer (score 9):

[JsonLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) is good for validating and formatting JSON.

Comment: JsonLint is a great tool for quickly validating JSON output.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, there's a great json formatter extension at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa

Answer (score 5):

What language??  There are different tools for almost every imaginable programming language, since they all have different syntactic rules and conventions.

Good ol' [`indent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) is a nice, customizable, command-line utility to format C and C++ programs.

Comment: Since the question asked for "online beautifier", do you know of any Web frontends to indent?

Answer (score 5):

It depends of the language, and of the architecture you are using.

[image] [image]

For example, in a php platform, you can format almost language with **[GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)**

As [bluish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505893/bluish) comments, GeSHi is a generic syntax highlighter, with no beautification feature. It is more used on the server side, and combine it with a beautification tool can be tricky, as illustrated with this [GeSHi drupal ticket](http://drupal.org/node/1054200).

Comment: -1 has no beaufitication, only hightlighting

Comment: @bluish: true. I have included your comment in my answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for the edit. I thought I lost those images for good.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Quick Highlighter](http://quickhighlighter.com/) a lot.  Works great for a huge list of languages.

Comment: -1 OP didn't ask about highlighters. This doesn't do formatting/beautifying.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com). There is a multi-language support(java, c, c++, c#, vb, haskell, ruby, javascript, lua, HTML, SQL, Tcl, Perl, JSON, groovy...)

Here is a sample ["Generate LiquiBase changeLogs using Groovy"](https://gist.github.com/2027501)

Comment: Dude, it's really beautiful. I'd choose this as the answer  :-)  Thanks…

Comment: its only showing pasted code. How to format that ?

Comment: that is correct, it is a code beautifier and code snippets storage. It has some cool features (like share, star and private snippets).

Comment: checked most of links on this page. This one is best.

Comment: -1, This is a code highlighter not a code beautifier / formatter.