# How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

Is there a way to get the (to-be-generated) SQL from a Hibernate `Criteria`?

Ideally, I would have something like:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Operator.class);

... build up the criteria ...
... and then do something like ...

String sql = criteria.toSql()

(But this of course does not exist)
```

The idea would then be to use the SQL as part of a huge 'MINUS' query (I need to find the differences between 2 identical schemas - identical in structure, not in data - and the MINUS is not supported by Hibernate)

(BTW I know I can check the SQL from the log files)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I've done something like this using Spring AOP so I could grab the sql, parameters, errors, and execution time for any query run in the application whether it was HQL, Criteria, or native SQL.

This is obviously fragile, insecure, subject to break with changes in Hibernate, etc, but it illustrates that it's possible to get the SQL:

```
CriteriaImpl c = (CriteriaImpl)query;
SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl)c.getSession();
SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor)s.getSessionFactory();
String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors( c.getEntityOrClassName() );
CriteriaLoader loader = new CriteriaLoader((OuterJoinLoadable)factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]),
    factory, c, implementors[0], s.getEnabledFilters());
Field f = OuterJoinLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sql");
f.setAccessible(true);
String sql = (String)f.get(loader);
```

Wrap the entire thing in a try/catch and use at your own risk.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more portable to redirect the hibernate log to a string temporarily?

Comment: Possibly, but if multiple threads were executing SQL at the same time, it may be hard to figure out which log messages go with the SQL you are trying to capture. An interceptor using onPrepareStatement would get you the SQL too, but the OP asked for a way to get the SQL for a given Criteria object.

Comment: Is there a way to also get the parameters of the SQL query printed out?

Comment: Here is my method to get the parameters: https://gist.github.com/bdeterling/5563683. I haven't revisited it in about 4 years.

Comment: If you're using Hibernate 5.x with JPA, and have a javax.persistence.Query instance, this works: return new org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.BasicFormatterImpl().format(query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).getQueryString());

Comment: My Entity associated Criteria query has a oneTomany relationship with another table. So CriteriaQuery.list() result is a joined result. But converted sql string doesn't contains any joining?

Answer (score 50):

Here's "another" way to get the SQL  :

```
CriteriaImpl criteriaImpl = (CriteriaImpl)criteria;
SessionImplementor session = criteriaImpl.getSession();
SessionFactoryImplementor factory = session.getFactory();
CriteriaQueryTranslator translator=new CriteriaQueryTranslator(factory,criteriaImpl,criteriaImpl.getEntityOrClassName(),CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS);
String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors( criteriaImpl.getEntityOrClassName() );

CriteriaJoinWalker walker = new CriteriaJoinWalker((OuterJoinLoadable)factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]), 
                        translator,
                        factory, 
                        criteriaImpl, 
                        criteriaImpl.getEntityOrClassName(), 
                        session.getLoadQueryInfluencers()   );

String sql=walker.getSQLString();
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works out great except for one thing. It doesn't print out correctly when my criteria is having criteria.setMaxResults(n). It doesn't shot that requirement in the generated statement. Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks, helped me to debug an application I had to work on and to find the error immediately.

Comment: Nice answer. I've adapted this to run in a single line so it can be easily run in a debug session or added to a watch list etc. See answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481#46788621

Comment: My Entity associated Criteria query has a oneTomany relationship with another table. So CriteriaQuery.list() result is a joined result. But converted sql string doesn't contains any joining?

Comment: May be not related but how to fit it  for 

`@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("select c from Employee c  where  c.login_time > :timeOfLogin") 
    public List<Employee> findEvasiveEmployees(@Param("timeOfLogin") LocalDateTime timeOfLogin); 
}`

Answer (score 11):

For those using NHibernate, this is a port of [ram]'s code

```
public static string GenerateSQL(ICriteria criteria)
    {
        NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl criteriaImpl = (NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl)criteria;
        NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session = criteriaImpl.Session;
        NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor factory = session.Factory;

        NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator translator = 
            new NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator(
                factory, 
                criteriaImpl, 
                criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName, 
                NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.RootSqlAlias);

        String[] implementors = factory.GetImplementors(criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName);

        NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker walker = new NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker(
            (NHibernate.Persister.Entity.IOuterJoinLoadable)factory.GetEntityPersister(implementors[0]),
                                translator,
                                factory,
                                criteriaImpl,
                                criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName,
                                session.EnabledFilters);

        return walker.SqlString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: does you know how to get values of parameters in that query ??

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Hibernate 3.6 you can use the code in the accepted answer (provided by Brian Deterling) with slight modification:

```
  CriteriaImpl c = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
  SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl) c.getSession();
  SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) s.getSessionFactory();
  String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors(c.getEntityOrClassName());
  LoadQueryInfluencers lqis = new LoadQueryInfluencers();
  CriteriaLoader loader = new CriteriaLoader((OuterJoinLoadable) factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]), factory, c, implementors[0], lqis);
  Field f = OuterJoinLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sql");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  String sql = (String) f.get(loader);
```

Answer (score 4):

I like this if you want to get just some parts of the query:

```
new CriteriaQueryTranslator(
    factory,
    executableCriteria,
    executableCriteria.getEntityOrClassName(), 
    CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS)
        .getWhereCondition();
```

For instance something like this:

```
String where = new CriteriaQueryTranslator(
    factory,
    executableCriteria,
    executableCriteria.getEntityOrClassName(), 
    CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS)
        .getWhereCondition();

String sql = "update my_table this_ set this_.status = 0 where " + where;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method I used and worked for me

```
public static String toSql(Session session, Criteria criteria){
    String sql="";
    Object[] parameters = null;
    try{
        CriteriaImpl c = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
        SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl)c.getSession();
        SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor)s.getSessionFactory();
        String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors( c.getEntityOrClassName() );
        CriteriaLoader loader = new CriteriaLoader((OuterJoinLoadable)factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]), factory, c, implementors[0], s.getEnabledFilters());
        Field f = OuterJoinLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sql");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        sql = (String)f.get(loader);
        Field fp = CriteriaLoader.class.getDeclaredField("traslator");
        fp.setAccessible(true);
        CriteriaQueryTranslator translator = (CriteriaQueryTranslator) fp.get(loader);
        parameters = translator.getQueryParameters().getPositionalParameterValues();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if (sql !=null){
        int fromPosition = sql.indexOf(" from ");
        sql = "SELECT * "+ sql.substring(fromPosition);

        if (parameters!=null && parameters.length>0){
            for (Object val : parameters) {
                String value="%";
                if(val instanceof Boolean){
                    value = ((Boolean)val)?"1":"0";
                }else if (val instanceof String){
                    value = "'"+val+"'";
                }
                sql = sql.replaceFirst("\\?", value);
            }
        }
    }
    return sql.replaceAll("left outer join", "\nleft outer join").replace(" and ", "\nand ").replace(" on ", "\non ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. There's however a little typo ("traslator" should be "translator"). And when replacing the CriteriaLoader constructor call with the one from @Michael ' s answer it'll also work with hibernate 3.6+ (tested with 4.1.9)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wishing to do this in a single line (e.g in the Display/Immediate window, a watch expression or similar in a debug session), the following will do so and "pretty print" the SQL:

```
new org.hibernate.jdbc.util.BasicFormatterImpl().format((new org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker((org.hibernate.persister.entity.OuterJoinLoadable)((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory().getEntityPersister(((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory().getImplementors(((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getEntityOrClassName())[0]),new org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator(((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory(),((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit),((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getEntityOrClassName(),org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS),((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory(),(org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit,((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getEntityOrClassName(),((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getEnabledFilters())).getSQLString());
```

...or here's an easier to read version:

```
new org.hibernate.jdbc.util.BasicFormatterImpl().format(
  (new org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker(
     (org.hibernate.persister.entity.OuterJoinLoadable)
      ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory().getEntityPersister(
        ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory().getImplementors(
          ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getEntityOrClassName())[0]),
     new org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator(
          ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory(),
          ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit),
          ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getEntityOrClassName(),
          org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS),
     ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getFactory(),
     (org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit,
     ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getEntityOrClassName(),
     ((org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl)crit).getSession().getEnabledFilters()
   )
  ).getSQLString()
);
```

**Notes:**

1. The answer is based on [the solution posted by ramdane.i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/46788621#3888873).
2. It assumes the [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) object is named `crit`. *If named differently, do a search and replace*.
3. It assumes the Hibernate version is later than 3.3.2.GA but earlier than 4.0 in order to use [BasicFormatterImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/util/BasicFormatterImpl.html) to "pretty print" the HQL. *If using a different version, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312552#559120) for how to modify. Or perhaps just remove the pretty printing entirely as it's just a "nice to have"*.
4. It's using [`getEnabledFilters`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/engine/SessionImplementor.html#getEnabledFilters()) rather than [`getLoadQueryInfluencers()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/engine/SessionImplementor.html#getLoadQueryInfluencers()) for backwards compatibility since the latter was introduced in a later version of Hibernate (3.5???)
5. It doesn't output the actual parameter values used if the query is parameterized.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on user3715338's answer (with a small spelling error corrected) and mixed with Michael's answer for Hibernate 3.6 - based on the accepted answer from Brian Deterling. I then extended it (for PostgreSQL) with a couple more types replacing the questionmarks:

```
public static String toSql(Criteria criteria)
{
    String sql = "";
    Object[] parameters = null;
    try
    {
        CriteriaImpl criteriaImpl = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
        SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) criteriaImpl.getSession();
        SessionFactoryImplementor factory = sessionImpl.getSessionFactory();
        String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors(criteriaImpl.getEntityOrClassName());
        OuterJoinLoadable persister = (OuterJoinLoadable) factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]);
        LoadQueryInfluencers loadQueryInfluencers = new LoadQueryInfluencers();
        CriteriaLoader loader = new CriteriaLoader(persister, factory,
            criteriaImpl, implementors[0].toString(), loadQueryInfluencers);
        Field f = OuterJoinLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sql");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        sql = (String) f.get(loader);
        Field fp = CriteriaLoader.class.getDeclaredField("translator");
        fp.setAccessible(true);
        CriteriaQueryTranslator translator = (CriteriaQueryTranslator) fp.get(loader);
        parameters = translator.getQueryParameters().getPositionalParameterValues();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if (sql != null)
    {
        int fromPosition = sql.indexOf(" from ");
        sql = "\nSELECT * " + sql.substring(fromPosition);

        if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0)
        {
            for (Object val : parameters)
            {
                String value = "%";
                if (val instanceof Boolean)
                {
                    value = ((Boolean) val) ? "1" : "0";
                }
                else if (val instanceof String)
                {
                    value = "'" + val + "'";
                }
                else if (val instanceof Number)
                {
                    value = val.toString();
                }
                else if (val instanceof Class)
                {
                    value = "'" + ((Class) val).getCanonicalName() + "'";
                }
                else if (val instanceof Date)
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                    value = "'" + sdf.format((Date) val) + "'";
                }
                else if (val instanceof Enum)
                {
                    value = "" + ((Enum) val).ordinal();
                }
                else
                {
                    value = val.toString();
                }
                sql = sql.replaceFirst("\\?", value);
            }
        }
    }
    return sql.replaceAll("left outer join", "\nleft outer join").replaceAll(
        " and ", "\nand ").replaceAll(" on ", "\non ").replaceAll("<>",
        "!=").replaceAll("<", " < ").replaceAll(">", " > ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is perfect, just the imports it is missing:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Property;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Subqueries;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.LoadQueryInfluencers;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;
import org.hibernate.loader.OuterJoinLoader;
import org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.OuterJoinLoadable;



  CriteriaImpl c = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
  SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl) c.getSession();
  SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) s.getSessionFactory();
  String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors(c.getEntityOrClassName());
  LoadQueryInfluencers lqis = new LoadQueryInfluencers();
  CriteriaLoader loader = new CriteriaLoader((OuterJoinLoadable) factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]), factory, c, implementors[0], lqis);
  Field f = OuterJoinLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sql");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  String sql = (String) f.get(loader);
```

Comment: May be not related but how to fit it  for _org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query_

`@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("select c from Employee c  where  c.login_time > :timeOfLogin") 
    public List<Employee> findEvasiveEmployees(@Param("timeOfLogin") LocalDateTime timeOfLogin); 
}`