# Can I access generated query without executing it?

Tags: castle-activerecord, castle

I know how to enable debugging so all queries that get run appear in my console. Is there any way to simply output the generated query without executing it?

Comment: why? some kind of what-if testing?

Comment: No particular reason. I was simply wondering if it were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't. NHibernate wouldn't know what to return as a result of the query method if it didn't execute the actual SQL against an actual database. For example:

```
Client[] = Client.FindAll();
```

The method has to return some collection of clients, and if ActiveRecord/NHibernate didn't send the SQL to the database it wouldn't know what to return.

Comment: Thank you. I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882583/hibernate-and-dry-running-hql-queries-statically which is related.

Comment: In retrospective, I think I misread the question, I don't see why NHibernate couldn't expose a method that just outputs the generated query so that the user can do with it whatever she wants. Of course, if wouldn't be the same methods we regularly use to run queries...