# Getting SQL from Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working with hibnernate and I've a piece of code like:

```
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(objectClass);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("myFields"));
    System.out.println("SQL: " + criteria.getSQL()); <-- How can I do this?
    return criteria.list();
```

I'd like to print the SQL (or HQL) to the console, for debugging, but I can't find any method to get this kind of information.

I've already seen many answers on stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701510/get-sql-query-from-nhibernate-criteria-before-the-criteria-executes) but those are old questions and I dosen't find any useful answer.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this -- edit your Hibernate configuration.

You can set up

```
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

to enable the logging of all the generated SQL statements to the console.

Moreover you can set up

```
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.use_sql_comments = true
```

to make it more readable

Read more about Hibernate configuration [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

if you use `persistance.xml` then you add property

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Ooooh very interesting... could you please tell me where can I find this file? Thank you

Comment: @Alessandro how the way do you choise, jpa + persistance or hibernare.cfg and xml ?

Comment: It's an existing project, I only have to do a little fix

Comment: try find file `persistance.xml` in project catalog