# How to set show_sql Hibernate parameter for a single method?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to set show_sql hibernate parameter inside java code in hibernate method, so that it can print the actual SQL query for that specific method only.

I Know using below configuration it can be done

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

But it will print all sql for all hibernate calls. I want specific for few methods
Ex.

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomerListByActive(boolean isActive) {
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("isActive", isActive));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("delFlag", false));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
        customerList = criteria.list();        
        **//Print SQL Method Syntax will come here**
        return customerList;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging)

Comment: Thanks @Vash. Its the same I was looking for. Just need for performance check in pre-production. For production environment its too risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vash has given link above, which has detailed the different approaches.

But for reference to this question, and which I have used in my code is as below

```
try {
            CriteriaImpl c = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
            SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl) c.getSession();
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) s.getSessionFactory();
            String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors(c.getEntityOrClassName());
            CriteriaLoader loader = new CriteriaLoader((OuterJoinLoadable) factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]),
                    factory, c, implementors[0], s.getEnabledFilters());
            Field f = OuterJoinLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sql");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            String sql = (String) f.get(loader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

**Its very very risky to use for Production Environment.**

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ended up having to change some things due to the version of Hibernate we're on these days.  Simply change s.getEnabledFilters() to s.getLoadQueryInfluencers(  ).

Answer (score 3):

you can enable or disable logging of SQL by below code.

```
Logger sqlLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");
sqlLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

... do your stuff ...

sqlLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this to change the logging level for all the other packages/class to a higher level and keep the logging to debug level only for this class/package.

Check how to set the log4j properties.  I'm sure there must be other ways to do it though..

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with hibernate properties or using standard hibernate/slf4j API calls.

You could try to write your own custom Logger that would filter out unnecessary output.