# Get SQL String from Hibernate query

Tags: string, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to get the string from an Hibernate query and process it later (so I can't solve it with `"hibernate.show_sql"`).

I have already looked at [How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging) but with that workaround I get the SQL query string but instead of showing the parameters value it shows '?'... Is there any way to get the full SQL string with the parameters values?

I mean, with that solution I get `"SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME=? AND SURNAME=?"` but I need to get `"SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME='John' AND SURNAME='Doe'"`...

Ideas?

Comment: have you checked any of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy). It's a bit older and I am afraid it isn't maintained anymore. It gave me good results in the past, anyway.

Edit: just found that it is being actively developed again. Works like a charm for me!

Answer (score 8):

You have to set `TRACE` level of logging to this hibernate package and parameter binding should show in your application log:

```
<category name="org.hibernate.type">
      <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>
```

Output example:

```
13:58:51,505 DEBUG [SQL] 
 insert 
        into
            s.audit
            (action, e_s, ip, time, userid, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
13:58:51,505 TRACE [StringType] binding 'Modify user' to parameter: 1
13:58:51,505 TRACE [StringType] binding 'E' to parameter: 2
13:58:51,505 TRACE [StringType] binding '164.20.81.65' to parameter: 3
13:58:51,505 TRACE [TimestampType] binding '2012-07-30 13:58:51' to parameter: 4
13:58:51,505 TRACE [IntegerType] binding '158' to parameter: 5
13:58:51,505 TRACE [IntegerType] binding '8851' to parameter: 6
```

And don't forget `'hibernate.show_sql=true'` property you said previously to show also the related SQL.

Comment: That's ok, but I needed the "whole" query, like: insert into    s.audit (action, e_s, ip, time, userid, id) values         ('Modify user','E','164.20.81.65','2012-07-30 13:58:51','158','8851')...

Comment: "whole" query as you said is not possible, this is the closest solution I think :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "the full SQL string with the parameters values".

Hibernate uses prepared statements, therefore it sends query string with `?`s and parameter values to the database separately, so that the actual query is never constructed.

Perhaps you can find a way extract parameter values from `QueryImpl`, but even in this case you won't be able to get a query ready for execution, because you'll need to handle escaping, conversion of parameter values to SQL literals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

JdbcLogger does this form you. http://jdbclogger.sourceforge.net/. Supports mysql, postgres, and spring integration.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) which allows to listen to different JDBC events including query execution.

You can implement [QueryExecutionListener.beforeQuery](http://ttddyy.github.io/datasource-proxy/docs/current/api/net/ttddyy/dsproxy/listener/QueryExecutionListener.html#beforeQuery-net.ttddyy.dsproxy.ExecutionInfo-java.util.List-) that receives `QueryInfo` with SQL query text and all parameters.