# How to get the JPA generated SQL query?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use JPA specification and Hibernate as my vendor. I need somehow to take the generated SQL Query which is sent to the the DB (printed to the sysout) and save it as a simple string.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

Let me make it a beat clearer: I don't need hibernate log. I need to be able to execute the same query on a different DB. Therefore, I need to get the SQL query as is, and hold it in a normal String variable.

**Edit 2**

Is there a util which I can provide it a bean and it will automatically generate an Insert query? can I somehow use Hibernate beans here? I know it's a beat complex.

Thanks,

Idob

Comment: Edit you question, it's not quite clear that you ask about spring data jpa module, spring can use jpa without spring data

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a nice clean solution. You might be able to pass the EntityManager into the Specification implementation via a parameter and then use the code found here https://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/05/24/how-to-get-the-jpqlsql-string-from-a-criteriaquery-in-jpa/

Comment: @ido-barash Did you got the solution for "I need to get the SQL query as is, and hold it in a normal String variable." ? If yes, please let me know.

Comment: No.  I gave up on it

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging . It is possible to get SQL in String using Hibernate

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to accomplish this in an implementation-agnostic way; something that doesn't rely on Hibernate or EclipseLink explicit classes.  That would make it portable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a bean like this.

```
@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}
```

If you're using Spring Boot add it somewhere to your @Configuration.

The logs created from this are executable in MySQL workbench.
You stated that you are using JPA and Hibernate. There's no other way except if the database you support are supported by JPA. In that case there is an AbstractJpaVendorAdapter that you can implement.

Comment: Cool. Able to see the sql statement in my console :)

Comment: And if I also want to see the parameter values?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is No. What you want to do is something that many developers would also like to do however it was not part of the JPA specification and thus the ability to get the generated SQL will depend upon what the vendor decided to do.  Using Hibernate the only way to obtain the SQL is via the log.

Comment: Found this with example for Hibernate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging . It is possible to get SQL in String using Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the log4j logging and add an appender for Hibernate to show the queries.

This has already been described here: [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)

Comment: This is not what I asked!.

Comment: I need to get the query as a string for later use. not view it in a log.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the insert query which Hibernate is executed on one database, and via code, run it on a different database via `entityManager#executeUpdate` or similar.

Hibernate does not expose the generated query as it is specific for the dialect of target database. So even if were to get the insert query, it could be pointless.

However in your case, you can create two database connections (via two `DataSource` or `EntityManagerFactory` whatever in your case) and call `dao.persist(entity)` two times for both databases, and let Hibernate handle the query construction part.

Edit: By query I mean native query here, HQL query would be same for both databases.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by a generated query but if you use Hibernate and you have `javax.persistence.Query query` you can get HQL string very easy (for EclipseLink it is similar). And if you have HQL you can translete it to SQL with QueryTranslator.

```
// Get HQL
String hqlQueryString = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).getQueryString();

// Translate HQL to SQL
ASTQueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
SessionImplementor hibernateSession = em.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator("", hqlQueryString, Collections.emptyMap(), hibernateSession.getFactory(), null);
queryTranslator.compile(Collections.emptyMap(), false);
String sqlQueryString = queryTranslator.getSQLString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add properties in instance of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ,Its working for me :-

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.common.persistence.dao")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.common.persistence.model" });
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("showSql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.query.substitutions", "false");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```