# jpql exception ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got DATE

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I wrote the below JPQL.

```sql
select e.name from emp e where e.date = nvl(:date,select max(date) from emp e where e.id=1);
```

When I pass the date value, it should run the JPQL with the given date value. If I don't pass any date value then the JPQL should run with `max(date)`.

But getting an exception `inconsistent datatypes`.

Observations :

If I change the query to :

```sql
select e.name from emp e where e.date = :date
```

It is working fine. But when I use `nvl` I'm getting the exception.

Comment: Space missing between select and max - is that a typo?

Comment: Also how are you passing param? Can you include the java code in your question?

Comment: yes it's a typo..

Comment: @query(select e.name from emp e where e.date = nvl(:date,select max(date) from emp e where e.id=1)
findemp(@param Date date)

that is how my repo will look like.


In service layer I will have below code

findemp("2012-12-12")

Comment: But "2012-12-12" is a string - do you parse Date object from it? Otherwise your code looks fine. Try [logging generated SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358934/how-to-get-the-jpa-generated-sql-query) to console, which might provide some clues.

Comment: yeah I'm parsing it to date and then passing that date to the method.

Comment: @Vasan Please see my observations above.

Comment: yeah generated the sql .. and I ran the sql in the db.. It is working fine..

Comment: I guess you could try a couple of things - 1) Try COALESCE instead of NVL (has same effect) and 2) Try making it into a native SQL query instead of the default JPQL. I don't know why your code doesn't work though - as I said I don't see any issues with it.

Comment: @Vasan Thanks Vasan for your inputs.. I tried using COALESCE, even though I'm getting the same issue.. Will there be any problem with the JPA version.. The JPA version I'm using is 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Using the NamedQuery can be helpful to you that works very well with above type of WHERE conditions.

For example:

**Entity**

Person.java

```java
    @NamedQuery(name="get_all_persons", 
    query="select p from Person p"
            + " where p.birthDate = nvl(:date, (select max(birthDate) from Person))")
```

**Repository:**

PersonJpaRepository.java

```java
public List<Person> findAll() {
    TypedQuery<Person> namedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("get_all_persons", Person.class);
    //namedQuery.setParameter("date", "2022-05-18");
    namedQuery.setParameter("date", null);
    return namedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) your solution might be as simple as upgrading to the latest version (2.7.0 at the moment), since [this might be resolved by the fix for this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2370).

If you are not using Spring Data JPA you should be able to do what was done in the fix and use `TypedParameterValue` to pass `null` values.
This will should pass type information to the database avoiding the arbitrary misattribution of types to `null` values.

[An alternative approach would be to use a `CAST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188918/casting-integer-to-string-in-jpql).

Since you did only post a tiny fraction of the exception there is no way telling what might be the correct types and where to exactly put the cast in the query.

Possibly the best approach would be to have two queries, one with the argument present, one without it and decide which one to call on the java side depending on the value of your argument.