# How to get the generated sql query from hibernate in my java code not on console?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

we can print the  generated sql query from hibernate on console.

Is there any way to get the that query in java code ?

Comment: you must be talking about generated SQL query from hibernate and not the hibernate query itself.

Comment: sorry. I have updated the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the JPA generated SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358934/how-to-get-the-jpa-generated-sql-query)

Comment: I have not tried this, but you can look into JPA Criteria API  https://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/05/24/how-to-get-the-jpqlsql-string-from-a-criteriaquery-in-jpa/

Comment: @Acewin its giving only the JPQL. Also tried with EclipseLink but its giving error.

Comment: The JPQL getting printed is actually a SQL query.