# hibernate batch select from get and criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I would like to batch a bunch of `get` and `Criteria` queries together and ask Hibernate to issue them in a single batch. Does Hibernate have such an interface? If not, is there a way to extract the HQL from `get` and `Criteria` objects so that I can manually issue them together myself?

I know it is possible to get SQL from `Criteria` ([How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging)), but I think it would be better to issue queries in HQL as I don't need to reconstruct objects from the raw SQL data that are returned.