# Get a specific value in Criteria hibernate String

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need extract some values on criteria String. 
The concept is to get the real SQL sentence and his parameters (no log)

For the moment, I used this for get the Select:

```
CriteriaImpl c = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
       SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl)c.getSession();
       SessionFactoryImplementor factory = s.getFactory();
       CriteriaQueryTranslator translator=new CriteriaQueryTranslator(factory,c,c.getEntityOrClassName(),CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS);
       String[] implementors = factory.getImplementors( c.getEntityOrClassName() );

       CriteriaJoinWalker walker = new CriteriaJoinWalker((OuterJoinLoadable)factory.getEntityPersister(implementors[0]), 
                               translator,
                               factory, 
                               c, 
                               c.getEntityOrClassName(), 
                               s.getLoadQueryInfluencers());


       String sql=walker.getSQLString();
```

And the result:

```
select this_.ID_ELEMENTO as ID1_72_32_, this_2_.ACTIVO as[....]where this_2_.FECHA_BAJA is null and this_2_.ID_TIPO_ELEMENTO=? and this_2_.ACTIVO=? order by this_.ID_ELEMENTO asc
```

The closest thing to obtain the parameters:

```
CriteriaQueryTranslator subCriteria= new CriteriaQueryTranslator(factory, c, c.getEntityOrClassName(), CriteriaQueryTranslator.ROOT_SQL_ALIAS);


       String root =subCriteria.getRootCriteria().toString();
```

And the result:

```
CriteriaImpl(com.itym.pojo.elementos.antenas.AntenaAnalogicaPojo:elemento[Subcriteria(tipoElemento:tipoElemento)][fechaBaja is null, tipoElemento=ANTENA, activo=true])
```

I need the "TipoElemento" and "activo" values, to replace on the first string.

I tried regular expresion, but not leave me.

If anyone knows how, or another way to get the real select, would be very grateful!

Comment: Did you check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/555192/3698894 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, if it isn't, correct me:
Both values are awaylable with this regex

```
/tipoElemento=([A-Za-z]*).*activo=([A-Za-z]*)/
```

Comment: Yes, using Pattern, matcher and extract the two groups. Thanks!