# How can I get sql string from hibernate criteria?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I work in mysql, and using hibernate criteria to build query. But I don't know how to get sql query from that criteria, so any one can help me, that could be grate, many thanks ?

tungosper

Comment: share your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging

Answer (score 3):

Just go to hibernate config.xml and add

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

You can see SQL query in your console after executing criteria or any hibernate query now.