# How to convert criteria to oracle sql query

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(STD_ID, stdId));
criteria.add(Restrictions.le(START_DATE, dateOfService));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(END_DATE, dateOfService));
results = criteria.list();
```

Is it possible to convert the criteria object to SQL query or while debugging in Eclipse is it possible to see the generated SQL query?

Comment: ok Thanks i will refer that one

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do with criteria API, but there are some workarounds :
[How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging)