# How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API in Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

I'd like to get the sql string from a [CriteriaQuery](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/criteria/criteriaquery) using Hibernate 6.

- [Query.getQueryString()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#getQueryString()) does no longer work in Hibernate 6 for `CriteriaQuery`.
- `SQLExtractor.from()` dos not work either because it just uses reflection to call [Query.getQueryString()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#getQueryString())
- [How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging#3888873) only works for hibernate versions up to 5.
- logging the sql statements is not enough in my use case. I need to store them in a string for processing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the [`SQLExtractor`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/20e64bb04257364db3446148d7ad6fe8739579a6/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62/src/main/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/query/SQLExtractor.java) from [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/get-sql-from-jpql-or-criteria/)? It has a hibernate 6 as well as 6.2 version.

Comment: Yes. `SQLExtractor` uses reflection to call `Query.getQueryString()` which does not work for CriteriaQuery in hibernate 6. Added `SQLExtractor` to the negative list.

Comment: Hello @BetaRide, could you please share the solution if you managed to find it?

Comment: Nothing to share so far :-(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an intentional design decision by the Hibernate team in version 6 as Hibernate moved to the [semantic query model](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sqm-semantic-query-model/).  I did find a workaround to do this in the following code. It's worth noting that the format of the HQL this method returns has changed slightly since Hibernate 5:

```
QuerySqmImpl<?> unwrap = entityManager.createQuery(query).unwrap(QuerySqmImpl.class);
String queryString = unwrap.getSqmStatement().toHqlString();
```

You can see some discussion around this in the [Hibernate JIRA ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15389) for this issue as well.

Comment: I had a ClassCastException because my TypedQuery is a Proxy. Thankfully, it is a proxy for `QuerySqmImpl` already. So I was able to work around this via reflection: `((SqmVisitableNode) typedQuery.getClass().getMethod("getSqmStatement").invoke(typedQuery)).toHqlString()`. You can check for a proxy by its class name: `if (typedQuery.getClass().getName().contains("Proxy")) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Library changed for SQLExtractor: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to take the SQL from a JPA Query, tweak it by adding a COUNT(*), and run it as native query using the original query's parameters

```
TypedQuery tq = entityManager.createQuery(query);

Field f = CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.class.getDeclaredField("jpqlQuery");
f.setAccessible(true);
QueryImpl impl = (QueryImpl)f.get(tq);

HQLQueryPlan plan = impl.getQueryPlan();
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from (" + plan.getSqlStrings()[0] + ")");

impl.getQueryParameters().getNamedParameters().forEach((key, value) -> {
    NamedParameterDescriptor desc = plan.getParameterMetadata().getNamedParameterDescriptor(key);
    for (int indx : desc.getSourceLocations()) {
        q.setParameter(indx + 1, value.getValue() instanceof Enum ? ((Enum) value.getValue()).name() : value.getValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: While the code can answer, can you explain it by quickly summary what you changed and why this should answer the OP question?

Comment: This code shows how to take the SQL from a JPA Query, tweak it by adding a `COUNT(*)`, and run it as native query using the original query's parameters

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Hibernate 6:

```
QuerySqmImpl q = (QuerySqmImpl)entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

StandardSqmTranslator converter = new StandardSqmTranslator(q.getSqmStatement(), q.getQueryOptions(), q.getDomainParameterXref(), q.getParameterBindings(), q.getLoadQueryInfluencers(), q.getSessionFactory(), true);
SelectStatement sqlAst = converter.visitSelectStatement((SqmSelectStatement)q.getSqmStatement());
String generatedSql = q.getSessionFactory().getJdbcServices().getDialect().getSqlAstTranslatorFactory().buildSelectTranslator(q.getSessionFactory(), sqlAst)
        .translate(null, q.getQueryOptions()).getSqlString();

Query countQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from (" + generatedSql + ")");

int i = 1;
for (Map.Entry<QueryParameterImplementor<?>, List<SqmParameter<?>>> param : q.getDomainParameterXref().getQueryParameters().entrySet()) {
    ValueBindJpaCriteriaParameter<?> value = (ValueBindJpaCriteriaParameter<?>)param.getKey();
    countQuery.setParameter(i, value.getValue() instanceof Enum ? ((Enum) value.getValue()).name() : value.getValue());
    i++;
}

return countQuery.getSingleResult();
```