# Is there a sql editor powered by HTML + css + javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

syntax highlighting + sql code format

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[**Code Mirror**](http://codemirror.net/) will do the trick. It's really nice. Very easy to run any code that you enter into it using `editor.getValue()`.

Comment: http://codemirror.net/contrib/sql/index.html

Comment: it's right for me thanks Zevan

Comment: I ended up using a combination of [Hibernate's SQL Formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4873441/148631) and Code Mirror to display formatted, syntax highlighted SQL on a web page. I do the formatting on the server side and then code mirror does the syntax highlighting.

This is because Code Mirror's SQL plugin can do syntax highlighting but not formatting

Comment: This is the perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

You could try http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

It doesn't format on the fly, but it does highlight and format your SQL when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following site for online formatting

http://www.sqlinform.com/free_online_sw.html

http://sqlformat.appspot.com/

OR

you can download free SSMS free plugin for offline which gives you formatting along with intelli sense support from

http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/

Answer (score -2):

use can also you Antlr javascript framework 
http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: Antlr is parser generator, the question is about visual editor!