# How can I format Java code in word document

Tags: java

I need to write a report which may contain some Java code pieces. I need the code to appear colored and line numbered. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 13):

Go to http://hilite.me/ and copy from the preview pane directly to word (tested with MS Word2007). Supports line numbering, but not well. Quite good for snippets.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to copy & paste directly from Eclipse. It preserves all the color formatting.

Comment: But what about line numbering ?

Comment: Sadly Eclipse displays but does not copy line numbers.

Comment: I initially try Selecting All the contents from my Java file in Eclipse and didnt work. I copied only class information and no imports (Like around ~100 lines) and it worked. Microsoft Word 2011

Comment: Works for Intellij IDEA too :)

Answer (score 1):

**-** Well you can **directly copy the things from an** `IDE` to your `Word Document`.

**-** And please make sure that you have **switched on the** `Line Numbering` of the Editor in the `IDE` before copying the code.

Comment: I use eclipse. I can't get the line numbers when pasting to Word.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:
http://quickhighlighter.com/

select with the line numbers copy and paste

You can also use another online formatting tools, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206441/online-code-beautifier-and-formatter) but if you want the coloring to work after inserting to a word document, the highlihted source code html source must be inline styled.

Answer (score -1):

- You can copy **with colors**, but first you have **to open all fold** otherwise colors gone.
- Line numbering copy is not working from Eclipse.

Explanation with example:
https://cmanios.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/copypaste-source-code-from-eclipse-to-microsoft-word/