# Complexity of Level Order traversal

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Function to print a particular level

```
void printGivenLevel(struct node* root, int level){
   if(root == NULL)
      return;
   if(level == 1)
      printf("%d ", root->data);
   else if (level > 1)
   {
      printGivenLevel(root->left, level-1);
      printGivenLevel(root->right, level-1);
   }
}
```

Function to print all level order traversal

```
void printLevelOrder(struct node* root)
{
   int h = height(root);
   int i;
   for(i=1; i<=h; i++)
      printGivenLevel(root, i);
}
```

Here I want to calculate complexity of function `printLevelOrder()`.
The resource from where I was referring it said it runs in `O(n²)`. I can't figure out how.
Because if I apply master's subtraction theorem to calculate complexity of method 1 it comes `2ⁿ` as `T(n)=2⋅T(n-1)`

Please correct me, if I am approaching wrong somewhere.

Comment: i can help with the formatting part  :) if you are on chrome, heres an handy [Chrome ext.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-code-beauti/pljeafjjkkbacckkollfejkciddacmeb) else this post has heaps of [online formatters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4735078/4749156).

Comment: really thanks a lot for support AbcAeffchen and Adrian!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have a skewed tree with `n` nodes. Something like :

`1
  \
   2
    \
     3
      \ 
       4
        .
         .
          n`

Now this tree has n levels. For each level `i` you call `printGivenLevel(i)` which goes through all nodes from level 1 through level `i` to finally print the node on level `i`.

So for level `n` you go through `n` nodes taking `cn` time.
For level `n - 1` you go through `n - 1` nodes taking `c(n - 1)` time
and so on.

So total time = `c(n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + .... + 3 + 2 + 1)` ~ `cn`<sup>`2`</sup> = `O(n`<sup>`2`</sup>`)`

Comment: Sorry I got what were you trying to say. But why it fails when I try to approach it through Master's Subtraction theorem.

Comment: I think the recurrence relation you wrote might be wrong. For the case I illustrated above, the recurrence would be T(n) = T(n - 1) + c. From what I can gather, you wrote a recurrence with a kind of complete binary tree in mind -> 2 * T(n - 1), with the 2 being -> 1 for left child + 1 for right child, right ? If that is the case then number of nodes is no longer n - 1 in the recursive call. It is rather ~ n / 2. So more like T(n) = 2T(n / 2) + c